# iReport 5 works different between 2 computers

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a report in iReport 5.0.0. The report is set to compile in java. The report retrieves data from SQL Server 2008 R2. After that I have created a group. I have also placed the bellow code in the "Print when expression" field.

> $F{MyIntegerValue} != 0

This works fine in my iReport 5.0.0 but somehow my friends iReport 5.0.0 casts the error:
"Incompatible operand types Integer and int". My friend also retrieves data from SQL Server 2008. Why does his iReport cast the error but mine doesn't?

Comment: are you using the same ireport version?
to which database are you connecting?

Comment: it should be the autoboxing error. for some reason in versions 5.x.x autoboxing does not happen properly. instead of `$F{MyIntegerValue} != 0` try `($F{MyIntegerValue}.equals(new Integer(0))) != 0`

Comment: I complimented with more information and I think you are on to something with the autoboxing error. The only problem is that it seems that the autoboxing is done correctly in my version but not in the other version of iReport. Is there somewhere in iReport where Autoboxing is turned on or off?

Comment: I am not sure about if the iReports allows that feature, one more thing you could do is `$F{MyIntegerValue}.intvalue() != 0`

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think my problem is not how to work around the problem, we already done that. The problem is that I don't understand why there would be a different between our 2 iReports to begin with. It causes problems when a report compiled on my computer doesn't respond to the same things when he compiles it.